# "will build" vs. "will have built"—any difference?

Tags: future-tense, future-perfect

My question is one I saw on a site it is.I want to know the difference between the sentences.

> 1. By 2025, I think we will build a settlement on Mars.

and

> 2. By 2025, I think we will have built a settlement on Mars.

Also can you please tell me the meaning of:

> By 2025, I think we would have built a settlement on Mars.

Comment: Of course both could be better put "I think that..." to separate the present thinking from the future building—but phrasing such as that quoted is not uncommon.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence uses a **simple future**. It means that *by 2025*, they *begin to build, start to build* a settlement. In the second sentence, however, a **future perfect** is used, meaning that *by 2025*, the process of building that settlement will **have been completed**.

So, simply put: In the first sentence, the settlement will not yet be there by 2025, but in the second sentence, the settlement will be completely finished and ready by 2025.

Comment: The only 'simple present' here is *think*, which is in both sentences. In traditional grammar *will build* is called 'simple future' and *will have built* is called 'future perfect'. And *will build* will usually be taken to signify completion; non-completion would be signified with a progressive future, *we will be building*.

Comment: You are correct. I updated my answer accordingly.